# Replacing one line with multiple lines using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add a block of code into multiple terraform repos and want to use `sed` to do it in one go.

So far I have the following but am receiving the error
`unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`

I'm

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory where you want to search for files
directory="infrastructure"

# Define the line you want to replace
old_line='  #### End of specific section'

# Define the new lines you want to replace the old line with
new_lines='  #### End of specific section

  snippet {
    name = "New snippet"

    content  = content
    type     = type
  }
'

# Use 'find' to locate files in the specified directory and its subdirectories
# Then use 'sed' to replace the old line with the new lines in each file
find "$directory" -type f -exec sed -i '' "s/$old_line/$new_lines/g" {} \;
```

I have a feeling the error is related to the multiline variable `new_lines` (which requires the empty lines).

Also, I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Anyone got any pointers? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you have GNU `awk` you can try `awk -i inplace -v a="$old_line" -v b="$new_lines" '$0 ~ a {print b; next} 1'`.

Comment: Gives me
```awk: can't open file -v \
 source line number 1 \
awk: unknown option -i ignored```

Comment: As explained this is for GNU `awk`. Your `awk` is probably not GNU `awk`. If you cannot use the `inplace` option you can try `awk -v a="$old_line" -v b="$new_lines" '$0 ~ a {print b; next} 1' file > tmpfile; mv tmpfile file`.

Comment: I have gotten closer by wrapping `new_lines` in double quotes and escaping the double quotes inside it. Error is now `: bad substitution`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the newlines with \n and make it a single line.

Please verify, don't use as is.

```
new_lines='  #### End of specific section\n\n  snippet {\n    name = "New snippet"\n    content  = content\n    type     = type\n  }'
```

Comment: Error is now
`sed: 1: "s/  #### End of specific  ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'v'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -i inplace '{
    if (/pattern-to-match/) {
        print "new line 1"
        print "new line 2"
        print "new line 3"
    } else {
        print
    }
}' <your_filename>
```

Comment: That looks like Awk, not sed.  Did you actually read the question?